# 401 unauthorized response when trying to use GET method using Bearer token in react (Postman)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, access-token

I am trying to show users (by GET request) from mongodb using and Bearer access token in Postman, but it says unauthorized and data is not retrieved from mongodb.

I am working on MERN, I have created a private route for login. I have mongodb in cloud and want to access protected route by providing access token ('Bearer + token') in POSTMAN, but it says unauthorized and does not show me the result. (status code is 401).

```
//FInd the user by email
  User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
    //Check for user
    if (!user) {
      errors.email = "User not found";
      return res.status(404).json({ email: errors });
    }

    //Check for password
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
      if (isMatch) {
        //User matched
        const payload = { id: user.id, name: user.name, avatar: user.avatar }; // create JWT payload

        //Sign the token
        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          keys.secretOrKey,
          { expiresIn: 3600 },
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({ success: true, token: "Bearer " + token });
          }
        );
      } else {
        errors.password = "Password incorrect";
        return res.status(400).json({ password: errors });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I expect the output should be user object with fields which come from mongodb in cloud. But unauthorized is coming. Literally, I am trying to create an a DEVConnector social site which holds profiles of developers. For this I have created Register and Login pages, Register user is working fine, when I try to login to get a Bearer token, it also works. The problem is that when i copy the Token and paste in other page to access protected routes it responds me with 401 unauthorized code.

Comment: Please provide your other protected route's code where you verify the JWT token.

Comment: Show how you doing your query in Postman

Comment: the api url is: http://localhost:5000/api/profile. and when i access it using GET request, i also put Authorization (key) and Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkNjc4YjRmYjUyNDZhNDU5NDBhM2Y3NCIsIm5hbWUiOiJCcmFkIFRyYXZlcnN5IiwiYXZhdGFyIjoiLy93d3cuZ3JhdmF0YXIuY29tL2F2YXRhci9kYjNkZmQxODE1ODAzNDc1NjhkYjYyYjA1NGIzZjVjNj9zPTIwMCZyPXBnJmRlZmF1bHQ9bW0iLCJpYXQiOjE1NjcwNjczMzgsImV4cCI6MTU2NzA3MDkzOH0.a2ZBbvtK_mdmQRz7C42QeflVfbwtTBKVjM8CnhrAS0A (value) and then hit SEND. but it says me unauthorized

Comment: I want to send you some snapshots, but how to upload images here. plz help me

Comment: @ahmedaburaihan, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Daniel, No i did not solve